# DASH MultiTab Callback Problems

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am working on a multi-tab dashboard with DASH and I have some callback problems.

**1. Problem: Button enabled / disbaled in connection with a checkbox:**
On my first tab there is a button that leads to the next tab and that should only be enabled if a checkbox is clicked. This is working. But if I unclick the checkbox, the button is still enabled even tho it should be disabled then again. Here my code:

```
@callback( 
    Output(component_id='start-button',component_property='disabled'), 
    Input(component_id='checklist- 
    conditions',component_property='value'),prevent_initial_call=True
)
def enable_start_button(conditions_read):
    if conditions_read == "I herby comfirm that I read...":
        disabled = False
    if conditions_read != "I herby comfirm that I read...":
        disabled = False
```

**2. Problem: Button enabled if more pre-conditions are set:**
A button should be enabled only if 4 conditions are fulfilled. However, the button is already enabled if only one of the 4 conditions is fulfilled. Here the code:

```
@callback( 
    Output(component_id='continue1-button',component_property='disabled'), 
    Input(component_id='contact-first-name',component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='contact-last-name',component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='contact-mail',component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='contact-company',component_property='value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def 
enable_start_button(first_name_checked,last_name_checked,mail_checked,company_checked):
        if first_name_checked != None and last_name_checked != None and mail_checked != 
            None and company_checked!= None:
            disabled = False
```

**3. Problem: 2 inputs should be enabled (here dropdowns) if certain conditions are fulfilled.**
However, only one of the 2 inputs gets enabled, the other stays grey. For example, it should be possible to choose a new wind turbine type and rating if before the user selects in another dropdown as a turbine type = new. Here the code:

```
@callback( 
    Output(component_id='new-turbine',component_property='disabled'), 
    Output(component_id='new-turbine-rating',component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='turbine-type',component_property='value'), 
    prevent_inital_callback = True
)
def enable_new_turbine(new_turbine):
    if new_turbine == "New":
        disabled1 = False
        disabled2 = False
```

I am already searching for a longer time for a solution since it seems not to be such a difficult problem. But I still have not found anything and I would be glad for any help!
Thanks a lot and best regards,
Lexy.

Comment: Hello man, it would be great if you can paste an entire reproducible example so we can try to run it and find what's going wrong with ease... I'm sure that I can help you but I need to understand what you have done or not, otherwise, we need to imagine what is happening on your side (for instance, we don't know if you have returned the values or not, if you've set the else in the if condition and other parts that are incomplete in your example)...  Regards, Leonardo

Comment: Hey, for the first example there is not much else to post. In the layout I have the checklist like this:
dcc.Checklist(options=["I herby comfirm that I read...."],value=[],id='checklist-conditions',persistence=True,persistence_type='memory')

And the button like this:
dbc.Button('Start',id='start-button',href='/apps/userinformation',style={'background-color': '#009993','border':'0px','border-radius':'5px','font-size':'20px'},n_clicks=0,disabled=True)

And the callback shows everything I have. Please check my comment on morten-s for returns! Thanks a lot for reaching out, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
The missing returns appear to be the problem.
Lets talk this through on the second Problem. By setting `Output(component_id='continue1-button',component_property='disabled')` you indicate that the Output of that callback will set the component_property of the button with the id `'continue1-button'`. This is the value you need to return from the function. Has the condition occured that the button should not be disabled anymore end the function call with `return False`. Should the button still be disabled `return True`.

As for Problem 3 you would need to return 2 values because you have two outputs, for example `return False, False` if both dropdowns should be activated.

---

first of all I cant test the things I'm saying right now and I'm no expert either, but maybe my two cents will help you :)

0. Are you actually returning the values? I guess you do, but just to be certain.
1. Problem: I dont know if it fixes the problem, but your if's do the same thing and are always right. Either `conditions_read` is the string or not.
2. Problem: I GUESS that there is no else statement, therefore NONE is returned and NONE resolves to False, therefore it seems as if the if statement was true.
3. Problem: I'm not sure. You talk about 3 dropdowns, but in your code are only two. Maybe you are not returning the disabled1 and disabled2 and therefore again only NONE is returned and only one gets activated

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply! :)
The return is a good argument. I tried to use it but then I get errors and also, what would I return? I am not sure what to put there. Any ideas for that?

With the if statements I tried a lot of different things, but they all did not work. I had the reasoning: If the first field is not empty (!= None) and the second field is not emtpy...and so on
If they are all true, I do this. But on the website nothing happens.

For 3, you are right. There are only 2 dropdowns and not 3, I put that wrong. And I guess here again the return thing is missing.

Comment: @Lexy I edited my original answer. Does this help? :) If not please let me know what the errors are that you are receiving

Comment: Thank you a lot! The return for problems 3 works, thats great!
For the other 2 problems I am still stuck on the problem, that the button gets enabled if the checkbox is clicked. But the button stays enabled, if I unclick the checkbox again:

def enable_start_button(conditions_read):
    if conditions_read == "I herby comfirm that I read....":
        return False

So I guess I need to put another if maybe like:
if conditions_read == None (so nothing is clicked), return True

But thats not working for now.
I am very new to this topic, so sorry for maybe being super unknowing :D